# getting error prisma and mongodb server to be run as a replica set

Tags: mongodb, next.js, prisma

i struggling with error my program. i build with Nuxtjs, prisma and mongodb, but i getting error prisma and mongodb server to be run as a replica set, can you guys help me?
this is my error message

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A replica set is required to run transactions in MongoDB.

You can convert your standalone `mongod` instance to a replica set following [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/). I have never tried this option, but it looks quite simple.

Another option is to create at least three `mongod` instances adjusting some parameters in the config file, such as `port`, `dbPath` in `storage` or `path` in `systemLog`, and add replication options.

```
storage:
   path: "/path/to/mongodb1" // then mongodb2 and mongodb3
   journal:
      enabled: true

systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: "/path/to/mongodb1/mongod1.log" // then mongodb2/mongod2.log and mongodb3/mongod3.log
   logAppend: true

...

net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27017 // then 27018 and 27019

setParameter:
   enableLocalhostAuthBypass: false

replication:
   replSetName: "yourReplicaSetName"
```

Run every instance, something like:

```
mongod --config /path/to/conf/file/mongodb1.conf
mongod --config /path/to/conf/file/mongodb2.conf
mongod --config /path/to/conf/file/mongodb3.conf
```

Finally, you have to initiate your replica set with `mongosh`, something like:

```
rs.initiate({_id: "yourReplicaSetName", members: [
   {_id: 0, host: "localhost:27017"},
   {_id: 1, host: "localhost:27018"},
   {_id: 2, host: "localhost:27019"}
]})
```

Comment: Is it possible prisma connect to mongodb without replicaSet?

Comment: According to Prisma [documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/setup-prisma/add-to-existing-project/mongodb-node-mongodb), the MongoDB database connector uses transactions to support nested writes, and the only way to make transactions in MongoDB right now is with a replica set, so the answer is not. You can always use MongoDB Atlas. They provide a replica set, so you only need to use the Atlas connection string.